# Rock Paper Scissors -- Loop -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am having issues trying to make a loop. When I include a "for" loop, the game will iterate in (i) amount, for (i) is the condition of the "for" loop. How can I get the game to loop until the player/computer/tie reaches the goal of "5"?

I searched and read through multiple similar problems on this site and have tried to replicate a resolution without any success.

Any guidance is appreciated!

function gameOver() is where I THINK I did not code my thoughts correctly.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
let matchResults = document.querySelector('.match-results');
let winnerResults = document.querySelector('.winner-results');
let playerPoint = document.querySelector('#playerPoint');
let computerPoint = document.querySelector('#computerPoint');
let tiePoint = document.querySelector('#tiePoint');
let matchOutcome = document.querySelector('.match-outcome');
let retryBtn = document.querySelector('.retry-btn');

let running = false;

let tie = 0;
let player = 0;
let computer = 0;

startGame();

function startGame(){
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        playRound(button.id);
        gameOver()
        })
    });
    retryBtn.addEventListener('click', restartGame);
    running = true;
       
};

function playRound (playerSelection) {
    computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();

    matchResults.textContent = `You selected ${playerSelection} : Computer selected ${computerSelection}`
    if (playerSelection == computerSelection){
        tie = ++tie;
        tiePointAdd();
        winnerResults.textContent = `${playerSelection} is tied with ${computerSelection}!`
        
    }else if (
        (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') ||
        (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') ||
        (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock')
    ){
        player =  ++player;
        playerPointAdd();
        winnerResults.textContent = `${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}!`
        
    }else {
        computer = ++computer;
        computerPointAdd();
        winnerResults.textContent = `${playerSelection} loses to ${computerSelection}!`
      }
}

function getComputerChoice() {
    let possibleChoices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    let randomChoice = possibleChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChoices.length)]
    return randomChoice
}

function playerPointAdd(){
    playerPoint.textContent = player;
}

function computerPointAdd(){
    computerPoint.textContent = computer
}

function tiePointAdd(){
    tiePoint.textContent = tie
}

function restartGame(){
     tie = 0;
     player = 0;
     computer = 0;
     tiePoint.textContent = 0;
     playerPoint.textContent = 0;
     computerPoint.textContent = 0;
     matchResults.textContent = ``;
     winnerResults.textContent= ``;
     matchOutcome.textContent = ``;
     running = true;
     buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        playRound(button.id);
        gameOver()
        })
    })

}

function gameOver(){

    let playerGame = false;
    let computerGame = false;
    let nanGame = false; //no one wins
    
    for(let i = 0; i < 14; i++){
        if (tie === 5){
            nanGame = true;
            break;
        } 
        if (player === 5){
            playerGame = true;
            break;
        } 
        if (computer === 5){
            computerGame = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (nanGame) {
        matchOutcome.textContent = `Game over! Tie Game! Try Again?`
        endGame()
        running = false
    } else if (playerGame){
        matchOutcome.textContent = `Game over! You Win! Congrats!!!`
        endGame()
        running = false

    } else if (computerGame){
        matchOutcome.textContent = `Game over! You Lose! Try Again?`
        endGame()
        running = false
    } else {
        matchOutcome.textContent = ``
    }
}
```

I am having issues trying to make a loop. When I include a "for" loop, the game will iterate in (i) amount, for (i) is the condition of the "for" loop. How can I get the game to loop until the player/computer/tie reaches the goal of "5"?

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML code, so we can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to work.

```js
function gameOver(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 14; i++){
        if (tie === 5){
          matchOutcome.textContent = `Game over! Tie Game! Try Again?`
          endGame()
          running = false
        } 
        if (player === 5){
          matchOutcome.textContent = `Game over! You Win! Congrats!!!`
          endGame()
          running = false
        } 
        if (computer === 5){
          matchOutcome.textContent = `Game over! You Lose! Try Again?`
          endGame()
          running = false
        }else {
          matchOutcome.textContent = ``
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate the time taken to code a solution, however, my issue still persists. The game keeps looping despite fulfilling the condition(s).

Comment: well, this is probably because you aren't returning anything. you need to return so that the function ends.